# Does embedding (concatenating) a user ID in a session token for logging have any security implications?

Tags: web-application, cookies, session-management, logging

Assuming there's a user with ID `123456` logging into a web application where the randomly generated session identifier to be stored in the cookie looks like this `123456zXRL9DWpPtaAhkPzhemQZE5P5F` (that is, prefixed with the user ID `******zXRL9DWpPtaAhkPzhemQZE5P5F`), what are the potential security implications?

This would be to generate user identifiable access logs throughout various hops in a system, web servers, proxies etc. without the need to come up with schemes to pass around the user IDs.

Thanks

Comment: GDPR *might* consider the user ID to be personal data (it depends on other factors that can be used to correlate to an identifiable person).  Do you have any EU visitors to your web application?  Google considers public user name to be PII for what that is worth.

Comment: That's an interesting aspect. No EU visitors for now, but that may be a future possibility. The application is a payment related service, so the user identifiable logs can serve as audit logs.

Answer (score -1):

It can have potentially serious implications. If the user authentication process use that User ID, an attacker can do a DOS attack sending wrong authentications data and locking User ID account.

If the User ID is not directly consistent to user personal informations (e.g. anonymization)  it is not considered personal data.

Comment: It's the same ID used for login, which is also a publicly visible handle (and stored in a cookie for rendering on the UI) similar to the "dotcom_user" cookie GitHub sets.

Comment: Login ID should never be stored on public area. If you need a unique identifier then use something else like HASH(Login ID)

Comment: Why is that a problem as long as it's a secure cookie only used for non-serious things like rendering a "hi *userid*" on the UI? GitHub sets a "dotcom_user" cookie with the username for example.

Comment: It's less secure than using a different information. Your security is based on server/client/browser security settings. One flaw on one of them and you give User ID information to an attacker. If you use something else like  hash(User Id) ... you have not worry anymore about it.

https://flaviocopes.com/cookies/